# Responsive/fluid email

Tags: html, email, fluid

I am trying to make a responsive email with fluid images and have been informed that I can't define my table width at 600px in order to have a fluid image. How am I supposed to define the width of my email if I can't do that? I don't want it to be the full width!

Answer (score 0):

If you working with HTML Email, please forget all you know about `CSS` and `Semantic`

```
<table width="100%" border="0">
</table>
```

Instead use table layout, like the bad old times.

Also take a look into this Project:

http://internations.github.io/antwort/

It gives you a base responsive Layout.

Comment: That's what I have been doing. I don't want my email to stretch the whole screen. Everything I have read says to set the width between 600-800px. I've used the "1999 table structure" already.

Comment: Edited, please take a look into `antwort`